# What is the difference between 'lastimar' and 'herir'?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, diferencias-regionales, significado

Recently I came across two words – "lastimar" and "herir" – that, according to my dictionary, both translate to "to hurt".

After some research I found out that some people believe that one simply is stronger than the other, while other people are convinced that one can only be used for physical damage and the other only for emotional damage.

I found another person saying that "lastimar" is very old-fashioned and hardly used anymore and "herir" is the word to use for both types of "to hurt".

Now, what exactly *is* the difference and when would you use which one? Are they really synonyms and I can pick either one? And are there any differences regarding these two words between Spanish spoken in Spain and Spanish spoken in Latin-America?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering first to what you were told about *herir* and *lastimar*:

> «Some people believe that one simply is stronger than the other.»

True, in general *herir* and its related words imply a physical wound, while *lastimar* might refer to a scratch. *Herir* tends to be used more in medical/technical speech, where *lastimar* is a bit more informal, so naturally *herir* is associated with serious injuries. Note however that you can say *Se lastimó mucho al caer* and *La caída le provocó una herida superficial*, which inverts the usual connotations.

> «Other people are convinced that one can only be used for physical damage and the other only for emotional damage.»

Not really. *Sus palabras me lastimaron* is synonym with *Sus palabras me hirieron*. There's an idiomatic expression, *una herida abierta*, that can be used figuratively to refer to a deep emotional hurt, in a way where *lastimar* cannot, but that's it.

> «I found another person saying that "lastimar" is very old-fashioned and hardly used anymore and "herir" is the word to use for both types of "to hurt".»

Definitely false. Both words are used, in different contexts to be sure.

Some differences:

- When used informally, *herir* is usually active: *Lo hirieron en la cabeza*.
- *Lastimar* tends to be passive or reflexive, in form or meaning: *Me lastimé la mano* or *Salió muy lastimado de esa relación*.
- At least in my dialect (Argentina/Rioplatense) it's not done using *herir* in the impersonal passive (*Se hirió la mano*).
- Newspaper headlines do use *herir* in the passive: *Dos personas resultaron heridas* or *Un guardia de seguridad fue herido durante el asalto al banco*.

Some derivatives:

From *herir* you have

- *herida* "wound, cut",
- *herido/a* (noun) "wounded person, victim with a wound",
- *hiriente* "hurting, piercing" (figuratively: *comentarios hirientes*).

From *lastimar* you have

- *lastimadura* "slight wound, scratch" and
- *lástima* "pity" (not semantically close).

If there's an accident, you say there were e. g. *tres heridos*, or *un herido de gravedad*. You can't say there are **lastimados*.

If something is hurtful, it is *hiriente*, not **lastimante*.

Answer (score 6):

They are mostly synonyms. To me the subtle difference would be that I understand an `herida` as a *open* wound.

> [**Herida**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KCceJga)
>
> 1. f. **Perforación o desgarramiento** en algún lugar de un cuerpo vivo.

So I (as a Spaniard) would favor "herir" or "herida" for those situations in which "there's blood". Otherwise I tend to use "hacer(se) daño" or "lastimar" for other sources of pain (like a contusion, a pich, a bruise, etc.).

> No pellizques a tu hermano, que le vas a hacer daño. Si sigues haciédole eso le vas a lastimar  <sub>(in this context I could even use "hacer sangre" but I would not use "herir", since it might convey a **more serious wound**)</sub>.
>
> Me he hecho una herida en la rodilla (there is a scrape or scratch, thus, there's blood)
>
> Me he lastimado la rodilla (I hit it and ther is a bruise, but no open wound)

Also, when translating "you hurt my feelings" I would favor "herir" (Hieres  mis sentimientos) to convey that more "piercing" nature of the (metaphorical) wound.

For physical damage maybe you could understand "lastimar" as "to hurt" and "herir" as "to wound".

Comment: Also, notice that "lástima" comes from "lastimar", and its more subjective than "herida", which would be its equivalent from "herir". Even though "lástima" would be more like sorrow rather than physical pain

Comment: I'd also add to Diego's good answer that, where both words are interchangeable, *lastimar* and its derived terms tend to be more colloquial than *herir* and its variants.